# How can I add multiple unique random values to a Pandas DataFrame efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string of length 20, with about 30% 0's and 70% 1's. So something like this '11101001110111011110'

I would like to generate 10 more strings with the same 1, 0 distribution.

Right now I can do this by calling

```
''.join(map(str, np.random.choice([0, 1], size=20, p=[0.3, 0.7])))
```

10 times.

However, for efficiency reasons, is it possible for me to call random.choice as few times as possible, perhaps once? 
Right now I'm accomplishing this by creating a dataframe and then adding a column that calls the above functions, like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([None]*10)
df['Stuff'] = ''.join(map(str, np.random.choice([0, 1], size=20, p=[0.3, 
0.7])))
df
```

However, each of the 10 values are the same.
How do I make them unique randomized values?

If not is there some way to 'vectorize' the np.random function so my process of generating these random numbers can be more efficient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your example is that you assign a single value to the whole `df`. You could just build a list comprehension for this.

```
l1 = [str(np.random.choice([0, 1], size = 20, p = [0.3, 0.7])) for i in range(len(df.index))]
df = df.assign(Stuff=l1)
```

Other way to make this work out is by creating the values in a `numpy` array, like:

```
array = np.fromiter((str(np.random.choice([0, 1], size = 20, p = [0.3, 0.7])) for x in range(10)), dtype=float)
```

If you want, you could look for the `dtypes` for this, since the string type raises an error. These are the ways I could figure it out. Good luck!